# concatenating strings in dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

My requirement is to convert the columns of a dataframe and concatenate them like below:

```
A   B   C   D   Target
    1   2   321 1_2_321
    2   35  123 2_35_123
    3   55  123 3_55_123
    4   33      4_33_END
    5   11  123 5_11_123
```

I am able to achieve it using:

`df['add'] = df['B'].astype('str') + '_' + df['C'].astype('str') + '_' + df['D'].astype('str')`

but I don't know how to specify the 'END' string for the last. The current code output is coming like,

```
A   B   C   D   add
    1   2   321 1_2_321
    2   35  123 2_35_123
    3   55  123 3_55_123
    4   33      4_33_
    5   11  123 5_11_123
```

Is there any thing I missed out ? anything to learn ?

Comment: `df.iloc[-1,-1] += 'END'`?

Comment: `df.tail(1)['Target'] += 'END'` ?

Comment: Sorry, edited the question now.

Comment: `df['D'] = df['D'].fillna('END')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `df.apply(''.join,axis=1)` to join the entire row. However, you want to join only B thru D (`iloc[:,1:]`). While processing for it, you also want to check if D is empty. You can use the lambda function to check for column D and then use the join accordingly.

```
import pandas as pd
c = ['A','B','C','D']  
d = [['',1,2,321],
    ['',2,   35,  123],
    ['',3,   55,  123],
    ['',4,   33,  ''],
    ['',5,   11,  123]]

df = pd.DataFrame(d,columns=c)
df['Target'] = df.iloc[:,1:].astype(str).apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x) if x.D != '' else '_'.join(x) + '_END' ,axis=1)
print (df)
```

Results will be:

```
  A  B   C    D     Target
0    1   2  321    1_2_321
1    2  35  123   2_35_123
2    3  55  123   3_55_123
3    4  33       4_33__END
4    5  11  123   5_11_123
```

Alternate, you can also do this.

Temporarily replace value of column `'D'` to `'END'` if value is `''`, and then replace it back to `''`. Then you can use the join directly without any condition.

```
df.loc[df['D'] == '','D'] = 'END'
df['Target'] = df.iloc[:,1:].astype(str).apply('_'.join,axis=1)
df.loc[df['D'] == 'END','D'] = ''
```

Answer (score 2):

Try any of the 2 below -

```
df.apply(lambda x: '_'.join(['END' if i==None else str(i) for i in x]), axis=1)
```

OR

```
df['B'].astype('str') + '_' + df['C'].astype('str') + '_' + df['D'].fillna('END').astype('str')
```

The second one will be more efficient.